# Broken Update Conda : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' for matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

There was some error while updating the packages and since then the error keeps coming up with every single `conda` command.

```
python3
Error processing line 1 of /home/deshwal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.1.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/deshwal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

Error disappeared when I deleted the file `

```
matplotlib-3.1.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth:
```

but I can not import `matplotlib` in any case. I have used `conda install -f matplotlib` but doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `ls /home/deshwal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl*`

Comment: I had to remove the Anaconda and re install it. It had all the packages for ML,AI and Deep Learning and I had used `conda update --all`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it by deleting the file:

```bash
rm /home/deshwal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.1.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth
```